# perform operations on CSV file

Tags: java, string, csv, split, delimiter

I am beginner in java so please help.
I am trying to perform some calculations based on a comma separated file called "input.txt" , but it difficult for me. Any help will be appreciated.

The above text file "input.txt" contains the Each field is separated by commas. I am trying to read the above file line by line and do some calculations based on the third column. I want to find the total bill of the customer "Harris" for the month and the rates for the distances are given below.

**So I want to calculate bill of Harris for the total distance he has covered.(2x4 + 6x6 + 3x4 + 8x7 ).**
When I try to split the delimited data using below line,it gives me an error: "variable currentLine might not have been initialized".

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(currentLine,",");
```

below is the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    
    public class CalculateBill{
    
        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
            
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String currentLine;
            try{
                
                
                while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                }
            
            }catch(IOException e ){
            
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(currentLine,",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because it can happen that you reach the code:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(currentLine,",");
```

before any value is assigned to the variable `currentLine`.

If the input file doesn't exist for example, creating a BufferedReader from it will fail, but the exception thrown will be catched by your `catch(IOException e){}` block; so the execution will continue and will reach the creation of StringTokenizer without having currentLine initialized with any assignment.

In fact the first assignment of the variable (`currentLine = br.readLine()`) takes place after the creation of BufferedReader, which potentially may deviate the normal execution flow.

Beside you can have your code compiled by adding a default assignment to `currentLine` like in:

```
String currentLine = null;
```

The compiler is telling you that you may have a wrong design in your code. In fact, if you fail in reading the file, there is no point in having the currentLine tokenized, as you don't have a currentLine value at all.

This should make you think that you actually want the StringTokenizer creation **inside** the `while` loop

Comment: Can you teach how calculate the bill,i dont undertsnad how take the elements of csv file

Comment: I can help with syntax, not with homeworks. Try to think how you would do in normal life, and then make the code do it for you

Answer (score 1):

Initialise currentLine where it is declared.

`String currentLine = null;`